# Query that returns all id which only have one value in a group by result

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table defined like this

```
CREATE TABLE OrderItemRoomings(
    OrderItemRoomingId int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    OrderItemId int NOT NULL,
    PaxId int NOT NULL,
    GroupNumber tinyint NOT NULL)
```

I'm trying to get all `OrderItemId` which, when grouped, have differents group numbers

Assuming this table

```
+-----------------------------------+
| OrderItemId | PaxId | GroupNumber |
+-----------------------------------+
| 101         | 501   | 1           |
+-----------------------------------+
| 101         | 502   | 1           |
+-----------------------------------+
| 102         | 503   | 2           |
+-----------------------------------+
| 102         | 504   | 2           |
+-----------------------------------+
| 103         | 505   | 1           |
+-----------------------------------+
| 103         | 506   | 2           |
+-----------------------------------+
```

I want the query to returns `103` because there are two different group number for id 103.

I can't figure out the `GROUP BY` query which would check all sub result detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT OrderItemId
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY OrderItemID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT GroupNumber) > 1
```

Use `HAVING` to do filtering on grouped sets.  Here we show only orderitemid records with more than one unique groupnumber value.

Answer (score 2):

Not as elegant as JNK's answer but using a derived query:

```
SELECT OrderItemId
FROM
(
SELECT 
    OrderItemId
FROM 
    OrderItemRoomings
GROUP BY
    OrderItemId,
    GroupNumber) AS D
GROUP BY OrderItemId
HAVING Count(*) > 1
```

Comment: +1 You answer works too. I will choose JNK one because I learned something with his answer.